# jQuery CSS conflicts in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've created this WP plugin that uses a jQuery UI Datepicker. Works great, does exactly what I want it to do.... except any WP install already running a jQuery UI CSS will be overriden by mine. Obviously this is an issue.

Here's my code, pretty standard.

```
function javascript_datepicker_booking() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
   wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker_style_redmond', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css' );
}
```

I've been looking at two ways of solving this :

**Option 1:** Is there a way I could load the CSS ONLY IF there is no jquery CSS loaded already ?

**Option 2:** Is there a way to apply my stylesheet to the datepicker ONLY (i.e. not tabs etc) ?

Thanks for your suggestions !

Greg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change priorty like this the cascading nature should resolve it:

```
 add_action( $hook, $function_to_add, $priority, $accepted_args );
```

As for a css solution it's hard to say without our html but try being more specific to only affect you own markup.

this like `section#your_wrapper > ul.your_classes.another_class` increase specificity.

Notice `>` selecting direct children and element names to only select elements with these classes

Stringing classes can also increase specifity incase you want to add a special class to all of your elements

**However** Since jquery ui already ships with wordpress by default you can use the dependency paremeter of  `wp_enqueue_script`

```
 function javascript_datepicker_booking() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker');
   wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker_style_redmond', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css', 'jquery-ui` );
```

}

Comment: Okay, I'm probably not Codex-litterate enough to grasp it all here :). How do you think should I rephrase the code I pasted with an add_action or additional parameters for wp_enqueue ?

Comment: I've added the way I would do it try playing around with _inspect element_ to see whats the best course. The rest is right there simply replace the variables with your values

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go just now and see how it looks. I'll come back asap to say if that did it or not. Thanks for the hint !

Comment: Raam, I'll mak you up on this down. You gave the only response which lead me to finding what went wrong on my script. This was peripheral to the answer you gave but you helped. Thanks again.